# Install java 7 from maven Chef cookbook

Tags: java, maven, chef-infra

I want to install the Chef `maven` cookbook from the community site, and select `java` version 7. To do so I have added the following attributes in the `attributes/default.rb` of my recipe.

```
# Configure java and maven
default['maven']['setup_bin'] = true
node.override[:java][:jdk_version] = '7'
node.override[:java][:openjdk_packages] = [
"openjdk-7-jdk", "openjdk-7-jre-headless"
]
```

This does not work, as it installs java version 6. I have tried other variants with the same result, such as:

```
# Configure java and maven
default['maven']['setup_bin'] = true
default['java']['jdk_version'] = '7'
```

My platform is an Ubuntu precise64.

The output of `mvn -v` is the following:

```
Apache Maven 3.1.1 (0728685237757ffbf44136acec0402957f723d9a; 2013-09 17 15:22:22+0000)
Maven home: /usr/local/maven
Java version: 1.6.0_34, vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc.
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: ISO-8859-1
OS name: "linux", version: "3.2.0-23-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

How can I tell the java cookbook to install version 7?

Thanks!

Daniel

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not working because you have not set the *node['java']['openjdk_version']* attribute. Here is the [relevant code segment](https://github.com/agileorbit-cookbooks/java/blob/master/recipes/openjdk.rb#L47):

```
node['java']['openjdk_packages'].each do |pkg|
  package pkg do
    version node['java']['openjdk_version'] if node['java']['openjdk_version']
  end
end
```

Another option would be not to set the *node['java']['openjdk_packages']* attribute. The [set_attributes_from_version recipe](https://github.com/agileorbit-cookbooks/java/blob/master/recipes/set_attributes_from_version.rb) contains logic to do this based on the OS.